# make text display vertically centre next to an image

Tags: html, css

I have this CSS which i am using to display a DIV to the left of some text:

```
#type_box {
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    margin-right:10px;
    border-radius:20px;
    float:left;
    display:inline;
}
.box_okay {
    background:url(http://s29.postimg.org/gjnuph0gz/tick.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

i want the text to be exactly in the vertical centre of the image (with the image displaying to the left of the text)

http://jsfiddle.net/P3CFU/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put a text into span and use `line-height` to make it vertically aligned.

```
span
{
    line-height:30px;
}
```

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/P3CFU/1/)

Comment: you should use the same height as the container div which is 30px i guess.

Comment: works great, i tried doing #ServiceStatus_Name span { ... and then in my HTML <span id="ServiceStatus_Name">Text Here</span> but that didnt work

Comment: its okay i sorted it :) +1 !

Comment: Also I would dump the float: left; and just do display: inline-block. Also I wouldnt use line-height, but thats my opinion, different way for doing things.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use vertical-align. Wrap your text in a span, and style the div with image and the span like:

```
#type_box {
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    margin-right:10px;
    border-radius:20px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.box_okay {
    background:url(http://s29.postimg.org/gjnuph0gz/tick.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}

span.center{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CZ5Pq/

This way if you decide to change the size of either element, you won't have to rework margins, padding, relative positioning, etc.